# Intuition behind (statistical) completeness

Tags: statistics, intuition, random-variables

I was wondering if any of the members of the MSE community would like to share his/her intuition about **completeness** in statistics. For the sake of "completeness", here's the definition, taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_%28statistics%29):

> Consider a random variable $X$ whose probability distribution belongs to a parametric family of probability distributions $P_\theta$ parametrized by $\theta$.
>
> The statistic $T$ is said to be complete for the distribution of $X$ if for every measurable function $g$ (which must be independent of $\theta$) the following implication holds:
> $$E(g(T(X))) = 0 \mbox{ for all }\theta \mbox{ implies that }P_\theta(g(T(X)) = 0) = 1\mbox{ for all }\theta.$$

Now, to give you an idea of what kind of answer I am looking for, here's how I think about (minimal) sufficiency: I think of a statistic as a partition of the sample space. In that context, a statistic is **sufficient** for $\theta$ if this partition does not result in a loss of "information" about $\theta$; it is **minimal sufficient** if it is the coarsest partition which does not result in a loss of information (superlatives carry a uniqueness connotation, which I am ignoring here).

Comment: "...would like to share *his* intuition...?" - am$\require{cancel} \cancel{\text{Wh}}$y

Comment: @amWhy What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Just saying - Wikipedia isn't a very reliable source.

Comment: @amWhy You're saying that he said *his*, and you're a her (Amy) - right?

Comment: Exactly, @Sanath!

Comment: Nice edit, @MTurgeon! ;-)

Comment: Also asked on Cross-validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94473/intuition-behind-statistical-completeness